# Stop program from running after try / except python

Tags: python

I made a program that takes values from treeview and calculate something when button is pressed. I put try / except statement inside that function.

```
def SumAll():
    try:
       #do something (calculate)

    except ValueError:

        Error=messagebox.showinfo("Enter proper values")
        pass
```

The problem is, program keeps running when `messagebox.showinfo` appears, and it gives the `ValueError`.
How can I fix that, and how can I put more than one error exception (`IndexError`, etc)?

Comment: Your question is somewhat unclear - what are you expecting the program to do? Where does the user enter the values? Inside `SumAll()`? Without a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve), it's hard to give advice.

Comment: A user enters values directly in treeview (its 80 lines of code, so thats why i didn't post that part).
When user presses the button, the program should divide values from two columns. But for example if user does not enter the value in one column or enters letters instead of numbers , the program should show (messagebox.showinfo) and not show the error in coamnder, but the program does both.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can re-raise the exception, and if the exception reaches the top of the stack, the program will exit

```
try:
    #do something (calculate)
except ValueError:
    Error=messagebox.showinfo("Enter proper values")
    raise
```

Or you can manually call `sys.exit`

```
import sys

try:
    #do something (calculate)
except ValueError:
    Error=messagebox.showinfo("Enter proper values")
    sys.exit(1)
```

To catch more than on in the same handler, you can do something like

```
try:
    #do something (calculate)
except (IndexError, ValueError):
    Error=messagebox.showinfo("Enter proper values")
    raise
```

or if you want different handlers you can have

```
try:
    #do something (calculate)
except IndexError:
    Error=messagebox.showinfo("Some message")
    raise
except ValueError:
    Error=messagebox.showinfo("Enter proper values")
    raise
```

Comment: It does not work, it keeps showing error in commander. A user enters values directly in treeview (its 80 lines of code, so thats why i didn't post that part). When user presses the button, the program should divide values from two columns. But for example if user does not enter the value in one column or enters letters instead of numbers , the program should show `messagebox.showinfo` and not show the red error in commander, but the program does both.

Comment: @aleksandarbeat Can you edit the question with enough information to reproduce your setup? [mcve]

Answer (score 0):

You can catch multiples by:

```
try:
    k = input().split()[2]
    i = int(k[0])
except (IndexError, ValueError) as e:
    print(e)  # list index error: 'Hello World', Value error: 'Hello World Tata'
else:
    print("no error")
```

this will guard against inputs that split to less then 3 items `'5 a'` as well as against int conversion errors: `'Hello World Is A Cool Thing'` (`'Is'`` is not an integer).

Use [How to debug small programs (#1)](https://ericlippert.com/2014/03/05/how-to-debug-small-programs/) to debug through your real program, the error you get above this except *is* caught. You probably get a resulting error somewhere else because somethings not right with the return of your function.

Comment: It does not work, it keeps showing error in commander. A user enters values directly in treeview (its 80 lines of code, so thats why i didn't post that part). When user presses the button, the program should divide values from two columns. But for example if user does not enter the value in one column or enters letters instead of numbers , the program should show `messagebox.showinfo` and not show the red error in commander, but the program does both.